# Objective-C getting mime type of url file before webview loads it

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mime-types

I'm facing a problem building a web browser with download functionality, here's my code:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = request.URL;
    NSURLRequest *req  = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    [conn start];
    return YES;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    if ([[response MIMEType] rangeOfString:@"video"].location != NSNotFound) {
        // Do something with that video
    }
}
```

This is currently working as intended, video files will be handled correctly but the webview will also load it, what i need to do is capture the mime type of the file before returning YES in shouldStartLoadWithRequest and return NO if it's a video.

I tried the sendSynchronousRequest method but it slows the app, I also tried:

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>    
NSString *fileExtension = [myFileURL pathExtension];
NSString *UTI = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (__bridge CFStringRef)fileExtension, NULL);
NSString *contentType = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass((__bridge CFStringRef)UTI, kUTTagClassMIMEType);
```

But I often get wrong myme types, last thing, I dont want to detect type by the file extension since urls can be formatted as aliases.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

NSURLConnection is dead so stop using it. Switch to NSURLSession. NSURLSession gives you a data task delegate method that lets you examine the response header and bow out.

Comment: But I do not in any way endorse what you are trying to do; it seems nutty to me.

Comment: Totally agree with this